# PHP image file upload error

Tags: php, image

In my form I have

```
<td>Boiler Image:</td>
    <input type ="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="1000000" />
    <td><input type="file" name="boiler_image" id="boiler_image" /></td>
```

In my php code I have

```
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES['boiler_image']['twp_name'])){
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['boiler_image']['twp_name'], $upfile)){
            echo 'Problem: Could not move file to destination directory';
            exit;
        }
    }
    else {
        echo 'Problem: Possible file upload attack. Filename: ';
        echo $_FILES['boiler_image']['name'];
        exit;
    }
```

Whenever I try to upload an image I get 'Problem: Possible file upload attack. Filename:' Did I happen to set up the input form incorrectly?

Comment: Shouldn't both 2 occurrences of twp_name be tmp_name?

Comment: Exactly what @Mex said, it's `tmp_name`.

Comment: change ['twp_name'] to ['tmp_name'] in both places

Comment: Thanks for the responses! I fixed `['tmp_name']` but unfortunately I still seem to be getting the same error as before

Comment: possible duplicate of [php file upload problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5147494/php-file-upload-problem)

Comment: Have you looked at this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/5147533/797495

Comment: I think that might be the issue, so I changed `$upfile = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/path/way/'.$_FILES['boiler_image']['name'];`though the problem still persists. If it helps I tried just echoing the file name `echo $_FILES['boiler_image']['name'];` but nothing gets printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ensure you have set the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute on your form. It is required for all forms that have file uploads.

Comment: Thanks! looks like this was my issue

Comment: Great! FYI If an answer works for you, you can hit the "accept answer" button on the left if you like :)

Answer (score 1):

The temporary filename of the file in which the uploaded file was stored on the server is located at key "tmp_name". So, change your instances of `twp_name` to `tmp_name`.

```
$_FILES['boiler_image']['tmp_name']
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php